# Show that $\int^\infty_0\left(\frac{\ln(1+x)} x\right)^2dx$ converge.

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

> Show that $$\int\limits^\infty_0\left(\frac{\ln(1+x)} x\right)^2dx$$ converge.

I have utterly no clue on this integral. Please give me some hints. Thanks you.

Comment: Its value is $\dfrac{\pi^2}3=2~\zeta(2)$, and, in general, by generalizing the value of the integrand's exponent to *n*, the definite integral can be expressed as a sum of [zeta functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function), $I_n=\displaystyle\sum_{k=2}^na_k~\zeta(k)$, where $a_k\in$ **Q**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since

$$\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}\right)^2=1$$
then the integral
$$\int_0^1\left(\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}\right)^2dx$$
exists, moreover we have
$$\ln^2(1+x)=_\infty o(x^{1/2})$$
so
$$\left(\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}\right)^2=_\infty o\left(\frac{1}{x^{3/2}}\right)$$
and then the integral
$$\int_1^\infty \left(\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}\right)^2dx$$
also exists. Conclude.

Comment: Can you please explain the third equation a bit?

Comment: We have $f(x)=_\infty o(g(x))$ iff 
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0$$ and the third equality is true because the second equality is true.

Comment: Sorry, I mean the second equation.

Comment: We prove easily by the L'Hôpital's rule that
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln^4(1+x)}{x}=0$$

Answer (score 3):

If you use the change of variables $\ln(1+x)=u$ things will be easier. The integral becomes

$$ \int _{0}^{\infty }\!{\frac {{u}^{2}{{\rm e}^{u}}}{ \left( {{\rm e}^{u
}}-1 \right) ^{2}}}{du}.$$

Now you can see that close to $0$ the integrand behaves as

$$ \frac {{u}^{2}{{\rm e}^{u}}}{ \left( {{\rm e}^{u
}}-1 \right) ^{2}}\sim_{u\sim 0}  \frac {{u}^{2}{{\rm e}^{0}}}{ \left( (1+u)-1 \right) ^{2}} = 1 $$

which is integrable. Note that we used Taylor series the function

> $$ e^{u} = 1+u+\frac{u^2}{2!}+\dots\,.  $$

Try to do the same with the other end of the interval and to compare the integrand with an integrable function.

**Added:** For the other end you should be able to see that

$$  \frac {{u}^{2}{{\rm e}^{u}}}{ \left( {{\rm e}^{u
}}-1 \right) ^{2}}\sim_{u\sim \infty} \frac {{u}^{2}{{\rm e}^{u}}}{  ({{\rm e}^{u
}})
^{2}}=\dots\,. $$

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind, I would like to evaluate this integral.
\begin{align}
\int^\infty_0\frac{\ln^2(1+x)}{x^2}dx\tag1
&=2\int^\infty_0\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x(1+x)}dx\\\tag2
&=2\left[\int^1_0\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x(1+x)}dx+\int^1_0\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)}{1+x}dx\right]\\\tag3
&=2\left[\int^1_0\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}dx-\int^1_0\frac{\ln x}{1+x}dx\right]\\\tag4
&=2\left[-\mathrm{Li}_2(-1)-\sum_{n \ge 0}(-1)^n\int^1_0x^n\ln{x}dx\right]\\\tag5
&=2\left[\frac{\pi^2}{12}-\underbrace{\sum_{n \ge 1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}}_{-\eta \ (2)}\right]\\\tag6
&=2\left(\frac{\pi^2}{12}+\frac{\pi^2}{12}\right)\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}{3}
\end{align}
It automatically follows that the integral converges. 
Explanation:

$(1)$ Integrate by parts

$(2)$ Split the integral into $2$ and substitute $x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}$ for the second integral

$(3)$ Simplify using partial fractions and properties of logarithms

$(4)$ Expand $\frac{1}{1+x}$ as a series

$(5)$ Integrate by parts

$(6)$ $\eta (2)=(1-2^{1-2})\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{12}$

Answer (score 1):

The integrand function is integrable over the $I=[0,1]$ interval since it is continuous over there.
Moreover, for any $x\geq 1$ we have $\log(1+x)\leq x^{3/7}$, hence the integrand function is integrable over $[1,+\infty)$ since it is positive and bounded by the integrable function $\frac{1}{x^{8/7}}$.

By exploiting the change of variable suggested by Mhenni Benghorbal, an integration by parts and a geoemtric series, you can also check that:
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\log^2(1+x)}{x^2}\,dx = 2\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{3}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln^{2}\pars{1 + x} \over x^{2}}\,\dd x:\ {\large ?}}$.

> \begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{\int_{0}^{\infty}%
> {\ln^{2}\pars{1 + x} \over x^{2}}\,\dd x}
> =\int_{0}^{\infty}{1 \over x}\,2\ln\pars{1 + x}\,{1 \over 1 + x}\,\dd x
> \\[3mm]&=2\int_{0}^{\infty}\bracks{%
> {\ln\pars{1 + x} \over x} - {\ln\pars{1 + x} \over x + 1}}\,\dd x
> \end{align}

With $\ds{\Lambda > 0}$:
\begin{align}\int_{0}^{\Lambda}{\ln\pars{1 + x} \over x}\,\dd x
&=\int_{0}^{-\Lambda}{\ln\pars{1 - x} \over x}\,\dd x
=-\int_{0}^{-\Lambda}{\rm Li}_{2}'\pars{x}\,\dd x
=-{\rm Li}_{2}\pars{-\Lambda}
\\[3mm]&={\rm Li}_{2}\pars{-\,{1 \over \Lambda}} + {\pi^{2} \over 6}
+\half\,\ln^{2}\pars{\Lambda}
\\[5mm]\int_{0}^{\Lambda}{\ln\pars{1 + x} \over x + 1}\,\dd x
&=\half\,\ln^{2}\pars{1 + \Lambda}
\end{align}

> Then,
>   \begin{align}\color{#c00000}{\int_{0}^{\Lambda}%
> {\ln^{2}\pars{1 + x} \over x^{2}}\,\dd x}
> ={\pi^{2} \over 3} +
> 2\,{\rm Li}_{2}\pars{-\,{1 \over \Lambda}}
> -\bracks{\ln^{2}\pars{1 + \Lambda} - \ln^{2}\pars{\Lambda}} 
> \end{align}

Note that
$\ds{\lim_{\Lambda \to \infty}{\rm Li}_{2}\pars{-\,{1 \over \Lambda}} = 0}$ and
$$
\ln^{2}\pars{1 + \Lambda} - \ln^{2}\pars{\Lambda}
=\bracks{\Lambda\ln\pars{1 + {1 \over \Lambda}}}\,
{\ln\pars{1 + \Lambda} + \ln\pars{\Lambda} \over \Lambda}\
\stackrel{\Lambda \to \infty}{\Huge\longrightarrow}\ {0\atop}
$$

> such that
>   $$
> \color{#66f}{\large\int_{0}^{\infty}%
> {\ln^{2}\pars{1 + x} \over x^{2}}\,\dd x = {\pi^{2} \over 3}} \approx {\tt 3.2899}
> $$