# Evaluation of $\int_0^\infty \frac{(x^2+y^2)^{-s/2}}{e^{2\pi y}-1}\cos(s \arctan(y/x))dy$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$\mbox{Does the integral}\quad
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\left(x^{2} + y^{2}\right)^{-s/2} \over {\rm e}^{2\pi y} - 1}\,
\cos\left(s\arctan\left(y \over x\right)\right)\,{\rm d}y\quad
\mbox{converge or diverge ?.}
$$

Here $s$ is complex and $x$ is real.

This is similar to Hermites' integral formula for the Hurwitz zeta function, but uses $\large\cos$ in place of $\large\sin$.

The limit of the integrand tends to $\infty$ as $y \to 0^{+}$, but I know this does not necessarily imply divergence due to examples such as
$\int_{0}^{1}x^{-1/2}\,{\rm d}x = 2 < +\infty$.

Comment: Check [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/880249/show-that-int-infty-0-left-frac-ln1x-x-right2dx-converge/880281#880281).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $x \neq 0$. We have, as $y$ tends to $0$,
$$
\frac{(x^2+y^2)^{-s/2}}{e^{2\pi y}-1}\cos(s \arctan(y/x)) \sim \frac{1}{2 \pi \: x^s \:y}
$$
which gives a divergent integral.

Now if $x=0$, we have, as $y$ tends to $0$,
$$
\frac{(x^2+y^2)^{-s/2}}{e^{2\pi y}-1}\cos(s \arctan(y/x)) \sim \frac{\cos (\pi s/2)}{2 \pi \:y^{s+1}}
$$
which gives a convergent integral for $\Re s <0$ or $\cos (\pi s/2)=0$.

Comment: Why does the first part "give a divergent integral" ? I know the integrand behaves like $1/(2\pi y x^2)$ near $y=0$ which tends to $\infty$ as $y\to 0$, but how can we be sure that the integral of the integrand is not defined; c.f. $\int_0^1 x^{-1/2}dx = 2<+\infty$.

Comment: @pbs This a **comparison test** for improper integrals. Let's say $x>0$ (the integrand is even function of $x$). Near $y=0$, you may write $$f(y)= \frac{1}{2 \pi \: x^s \:y}+ \mathcal{O}(1) $$ giving $$\int_{\epsilon}^{b} f(y)\: \mathrm{d}y= \int_{\epsilon}^{b}\frac{1}{2 \pi \: x^s \:y} \mathrm{d}y+ \mathcal{O}(1), \qquad \epsilon>0,$$ and the integral on the right hand side is **divergent** since it is equal to $\frac{1}{2 \pi x^s} \log (b/\epsilon) $ which tends to $\infty$ as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0^+$. Thanks.

Comment: @ OlivierOloa thank you that's very helpful.